# Optimizing Small MySQL Join Query

Tags: php, mysql, join, query-optimization

I have a list of venues in the Venues table, and a list of a cities/states in the Locations table. The venue is associated with an area code unique to my organization, referred to as a SOYID. The SOYID is made up of a geographical area - each row in the Locations table has a City, State, and the corresponding SOYID. **Some Venues rows have a SOYID, others do not; for those that do not, I need to find the SOYID for the city and state listed.** I only want to select those Venues in a specific SOYID.

This query works, however, it takes a few seconds to load; I don't think I am writing the query correctly. Currently Venues has approx 140 rows, Locations has 40,000.

```
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT a.VenueID, a.Name, a.PhotoID, a.City, a.StateAbbr
            FROM Venues AS a LEFT JOIN Locations AS c ON a.City = c.city
            WHERE a.SOYID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($SOYID) . "'
            OR ((c.city = a.City) AND  (c.state = a.StateAbbr) AND (c.SOYID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($SOYID) . "'))
            ORDER BY a.Name ASC";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you reference a column from a LEFT JOINed table (`c.state` and `c.SOYID` in your specific case) in the WHERE clause, you force that join to behave like an INNER JOIN. Instead, make those tests part of the join condition:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT a.VenueID, a.Name, a.PhotoID, a.City, a.StateAbbr
    FROM Venues AS a 
        LEFT JOIN Locations AS c 
            ON a.City = c.city
                AND a.StateAbbr = c.state
                AND c.SOYID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($SOYID) . "'
    WHERE a.SOYID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($SOYID) . "'
        OR c.SOYID IS NOT NULL /* LEFT JOIN found a matching row */
    ORDER BY a.Name ASC"
```

**EDIT**: Based on comments, this version should allow you do remove the `DISTINCT` requirement:

```
"SELECT a.VenueID, a.Name, a.PhotoID, a.City, a.StateAbbr
    FROM Venues AS a 
    WHERE a.SOYID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($SOYID) . "'
        OR EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                      FROM Locations AS c 
                      WHERE a.City = c.city
                          AND a.StateAbbr = c.state
                          AND c.SOYID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($SOYID) . "') 
    ORDER BY a.Name ASC"
```

Comment: I guess he can drop the `DISTINCT` now, can't he? Or use a `GROUP BY a.VenuID` instead of teh `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, I think it's probably safe to drop the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: If I drop the distinct, I still get repeat rows, so no, I still need to keep the distinct. Thanks!

Comment: @John: I added an alternate query that should eliminate the need for the distinct.